# Вопрос по JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing

Добавил слушатель для окна. При закрытии с помощью JOptionPane спрашивается: Хочет ли пользователь закрыть окно. Если да, то окно закрывается, если нет, то ничего не происходит.
Но это так должно работать. На самом же деле что ни нажимай (да/нет) окно закроется в любом случае. В чем проблема?

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
        Object[] options = { "Да", "Нет" };
        int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(event.getWindow(),
        "Закрыть окно?", "Подтверждение",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,  options, options[0]);
        if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            event.getWindow().dispose();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```